# Can't access API-key from .env-file

Tags: javascript, api-key, openweathermap, dotenv

We are having problem accessing the API-key from our .env file when trying to fetch in our server.js. If we add the API-key manually to the URL in server.js it works, so the problem seems to be the connection between server.js and .env-file.
We have npm installed dotenv.
In the .env file we have written the key like this: `WEATHER_API_KEY = XXXXXXXXXXXX`

Does anyone know what we have done wrong?

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import crypto from "crypto";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import request from "request";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
// import { stringify } from "querystring";

const mongoUrl = process.env.MONGO_URL || "mongodb://localhost/project-mongo";
mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

dotenv.config();


app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  let city = req.query.city;
  // const request = require("request");
  // const options = {
  //   url: `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY}`,
  //   method: "GET",
  //   headers: {
  //     Accept: "application/json",
  //   },
  // };
  const key = "*******************";
  const requesturl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}`;
  request(requesturl, function (error, response, body) {
    let data = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(response);
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      res.send(`The weather in ${city} is ${data.weather[0].description}`);
    } else {
      res.send(data.message);
    }
  });
  console.log(process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY);
});
```

Comment: I have no idea if this fixes the issue but have you tried removing the spaces around the `=`?

Comment: where do you load dotenv? `import 'dotenv/config'` or `require('dotenv').config()` ?

Comment: Fist, load value using dotenv

Comment: I forgot to add the last import, now its updated @Craicerjack

Comment: Whats logging when you log the api_key? have you tried testing for an error `const result = dotenv.config()

if (result.error) {
  throw result.error
}

console.log(result.parsed)
`

Comment: Can you share how your `.env` file looks?

Comment: Looking at dotenv docs and from what others have said, have you removed the spaces and quoted your api key in your dotenv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
import 'dotenv/config';
```

in place of `import dotenv from "dotenv";` and remove the `dotenv.config();` call.

Source and explanation: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import

And update the request URL (which you might have changed for testing purpose) to

```
const requesturl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${process.env.key}`;
```

Also, try defining your key without any spaces, though this is less likely to be the root cause.

```
WEATHER_API_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is not specifically about React, it might be helpful for those who use React. For a React App, Environment Variables have to start with the REACT_APP_ prefix otherwise it won't work.

`REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXX"`

Answer (score 0):

If your `.env` file is something like this:

```
OPENAI_API_KEY = "YOUR_CUSTOM_KEY"
```

Import `load_dotenv` and `find_dotenv`

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
```

Test if it works:

```
import os
import openai
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

print(openai.api_key)
```